# Custom functions for non-select queries Cake Query Builder

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-builder, cakephp-4.x

I would like to use the mariadb `INET_ATON()` on an insert query with Cakephp Query Builder.

```sql
INSERT INTO failed_logins 
SET email = 'example@test.com', ip_address = INET_ATON('192.168.0.1'), sent_email = 1;
```

Then I'd like to retrieve the data with `INET_NTOA()` in a select query.

```sql
SELECT id, email, INET_NTOA(ip_address) AS ip_address, sent_email FROM failed_logins;
```

How do I use these functions with an insert and select on the Cake Query Builder?
I saw [Using SQL functions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions) but couldn't solve my issue.

Comment: The custom functions section of the referenced manual seems to be the answer to your question. Have a go at it!

Comment: Probably but I'm too dumb to make something out of it. The `func()` method is used on the query object and I make the insert with `$this->connection->insert('table', $row)` there is no query involved but I'm missing out on something I know.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to use the connection instead of the ORM, or even the query builder?

Comment: @ndm I posted an edit.

Comment: I dind't say that you don't need to use `insert()`, if you want to create an insert query, you definitely need to call `insert()`, but you don't necessarily have to use the connection's convenience function, which is just a wrapper around the query builder insert with a retry strategy for the connection.

Comment: Yes I saw my mistake and corrected it shortly after. The query I built made no sense and I've FINALLY come to a solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of playing around I managed to make it work.

```php
$this->connection->newQuery()->into('failed_logins');
$newIp = $query->func()->inet_aton([$ip]);
$query->insert(['email', 'ip_address', 'sent_email'])->values(
    ['email' => $email, 'ip_address' => $newIp, 'sent_email' => $sentEmail]
)->execute()->lastInsertId();
```

Quite complicated and my IDE and PHPStan show me warnings that the function "inet_aton" is not defined.
I would have loved it if in the `values()` array I could have just done it like `['ip_address' => "INET_ATON($ip)"]`. Edit: This is not a good idea see comments. But something similar that stays safe can be done with `->bind()` (code snippet below).

**Edit**: Removed `'literal'` from the code snippet (thanks @ndm)

#### IDE and Analysis Tool - friendly solution

```sql
$this->connection->newQuery()->into('failed_logins');

$query->insert(
    [
        'email',
        'ip_address',
        'sent_email',
    ]
)->values(
    [
        'email' => $email,
        'ip_address' => $query->newExpr("INET_ATON(:ip)"),
        'sent_email' => $sentEmail,
    ]
)->bind(':ip', $ip, 'string')->execute()->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: I can assure you that you wouldn't have loved that, because that would require the right hand side value to not be bound/escaped, which would leave your code wide open for SQL injections! ;) As an alternative to expressions you can however always use [**manual bindings**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#binding-values) `'INET_ATON(:ip)'` and then `->bind(':ip', $ip, 'string')` on the query builder. ps, be careful with that `literal`, that is ment to insert data _as is_ (but it would need to be in the value side to work), which again would be SQL injection prone!

Comment: You are totally right. In this case the `$ip` comes from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` which safe as the client cannot modify it at will. I saw that I could (dirtily) archive what I wanted with `$query->newExpr("INET_ATON($ip)");` its clear however that this must not be used with untrusted values but would you allow it here or not? 
The manual binding is very interesting, I didn't know about that! I think I will do it like this; makes the most sense for me.

Comment: I would definitely never ever do that unless it would be 1001% actually technically required! But even then I would use whitelists or manually escape the input if applicable. While your code may for now use a value that stems from a safe source, there is no guarantee that it will stay that way, one day you might be a little careless when making changes to your code, or someone else who isn't aware about where/how the value is being used makes changes, and suddenly the input stems from an untrusted source. You never know what the future holds.

Comment: Right this is very possible. Always stay safe and bind stuff I'll remember. I like the edit now with `->bind` thanks a lot for this suggestion.